# LINQTOSql Missing parameter question

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

I have a long LinqtoSQl query in which several parameters I'm not forcing the user to specify anything. I started using a Select Case statement that would test rather or not a parameter string's length > 0 or if it's an int > 0. But I realized that I would have to test for each possibility and create queries based on each.

I did some searching and ran across a post in which the person answering the post was saying to negate a portion of the query use ||. After doing some more searching (and realizing with little c# skills I do have || is the OR conditional), I realized that wouldn't help me.

I guess what I want to do is something like

```
Dim r = From x in db.List _
        (if firstName.Length < 1 then ignore query
         else)where x.firstName = firstName _
        (if lastName.Length < 1 then ignore query
         else)where x.LastName = lastName _
        Select x
```

I knw there has to be a better way than IfElse'ing my way through this...I was about to do some funky stuff with a StringBuilder, but I'm not sure it would "fire", ie:

```
Dim sb as New StringBuilder
sb.Append("Dim r = From x in db.List _")
If firstName.Length < 1 then 
  sb.Append("Where x.firstName = firstName")
```

ughh, please tell me there's a better way...

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the fact that queries are composable. I'll write this in C# to start with, then translate it into VB afterwards if you need that. The principle would be the same.

```
IQueryable<YourEntityType> query = db.List;
if (firstName != "")
{
    query = query.Where(x => x.firstName == firstName)
}
if (lastName != "")
{
    query = query.Where(x => x.lastName == lastName)
}
```

Now just read from `query` appropriately. (I've changed the nature of the string conditions just because it simpler to understand "is this string the empty string" than "is this string's length greater than 0" - both will work, obviously.)

Note that you can't do this sort of conditional call in a query expression, but it's easy when you're just calling the extension methods explicitly.

Comment: I guess I need you to translate this for me...
I like this idea but...

I tried 
     
    Dim query As IQueryable(Of List) = db.List
            query.Where(x => x.firstName == firstName)
but intellesense goes nuts trying to input something else and then I get warnings and errors that x is not declared...

Thanks!

Comment: Just figured it out...
query.Where(Function(x) x.firstName = firstName)
Silly VB!!!


Thanks a million!!!

Answer (score 0):

How about...

```
Dim r = From x in db.List _
        where (x.firstName = firstName Or firstName = "") _
        And (x.LastName = lastName Or lastName = "") _
        Select x
```

Comment: The firstname and lastName fields are nonnullable so the firstName = "" would never return true...
I'm just not making the user specify a name during the search...

Thanks!